# Set custom start date in html

Tags: javascript, html, date

I would like to set a custom start date for a calendar. So instead of the Gregorian calendar's start at 0, 2016 years ago. I would like to start at something like 1980 and a custom month and day too.

So instead of a new year at January 1st, I would like November 5th to be the new year instead (but it's still called January 1st, but compared to the Gregorian calendar, it's November 5th).

Which means, when we (with the Gregorian calendar) have the date 2016-02-10, the calendar I make, I would like it to be year 36 (2016-1980), month April (as November is now first instead of January according to the Gregorian calendar), and day 15 (10+5). So 2016-02-10 would be 30-04-15.

I have this code, but I don't know how to get it to work. Is it possible to do or will I have write code for everything that can happen?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tmonth=new Array("November","December","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October");

function GetClock(){
var d=new Date();
//d.setFullYear(1980,0,3);
var nmonth=d.getMonth()
ndate=d.getDate(),nyear=d.getYear();
if(nyear<1000) nyear+=1900;
nyear-=1962;



d.setFullYear(nyear,nmonth,ndate);
var nhour=d.getHours(),nmin=d.getMinutes(),nsec=d.getSeconds(),ap;

if(nhour==0){ap=" AM";nhour=12;}
else if(nhour<12){ap=" AM";}
else if(nhour==12){ap=" PM";}
else if(nhour>12){ap=" PM";nhour-=12;}

if(nmin<=9) nmin="0"+nmin;
if(nsec<=9) nsec="0"+nsec;

document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML=""+tmonth[nmonth]+" "+ndate+", "+nyear+" "+nhour+":"+nmin+":"+nsec+ap+"";

}

window.onload=function(){
GetClock();
setInterval(GetClock,1000);
}
</script>

<div id="clockbox"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i was going to do something like this i'd probably get the difference between now and November the 5th (last year) in milliseconds which is: 8592904550

This means, you can subtract that number from the current timestamp to get the date that amount of seconds ago. I'd then take the current year and -1980 to get the year number.

```
$(function(){

    var el = $('.clockbox');
    var dateNow = new Date();
    var newDateStamp = dateNow-8592904550;
    var newDate = new Date(newDateStamp);

    el.text(newDate.getMonth()+1 + "-" + newDate.getDate() + "-" +     (dateNow.getFullYear()-1980));


})
```

You can see a fiddle using jQuery here: https://jsfiddle.net/fpmes8y3/1/

remember the getMonth is zero indexed so you need to +1 to get the true number.

Sorry if i've misunderstood your question.

Comment: No, I think you've got the basics down. Although, (though this might be me being ignorant...) the problem with this is that I get todays date (12th of February) equal to 5th of November. I want my custom calendar to be 1st of January when our "normal" calendar is 5th of November. As the code is now, I get that 1st of January will be on 10th of April of the normal calendar.

It might simply be some simple edit but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: I think it would work if I could add the amount of milliseconds between November 5th and January 1st the next year. But I get errors when I do that and it claims it's an invalid date. How come? Why is it possible to go back in time (subtract) and retrieve the date but not forward? Any suggestions?

Comment: I was looking at it all wrong. I had to do a small change to the code for it to fit my purpose (not in the question) so it does work, nothing's wrong. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, an updated js fiddle here with the new math and a slight change to the code. https://jsfiddle.net/fpmes8y3/4/

Comment: Could you explain the use of "$(function()) {" instead of something like this: "function date123() {"? The reason I'm asking is I don't understand the reason for it and when I try to make it auto refresh the script using "setTimeout()" it doesn't work with the way you created the script. Why? Is there another way of doing the auto refresh because I need the script to update. @Stephen

Comment: Unless it's important that the "$(function() {" is in the code for some reason, I fixed it by just setting it to "function NAMEHERE() {" instead and then using the setInterval(). So if there is a reason to it being that way, do tell me. But as this works, I'm fine with it unless it's bad practice for some reason?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @lubblig, '$(function(){' is basically just short for 'document ready' in jQuery. I used this as I was running the function when the page/document loaded. You can read more about it here: [http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp). You are correct in that you can just do function NAMEHERE() and call it from somewhere else within your script.